# Faker gem generating 2-3 letter strings

Tags: ruby, rspec, faker

The Faker gem generates short, nonsense strings instead of what is described. For example, `Faker::Job.title` generates `"et"`. If I have a feature test that expects not to find a Faker-generated string on the page, chances are it's going to fail if the string is "et". Surely this is unexpected behaviour, as nobody in the world has the job title `"et"`.

This is my code, the most recent time I checked it the title was as expected, but the role and category were not:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

shared_context 'with signatory attributes' do
  let(:first_name)   { Faker::Name.first_name }
  let(:last_name)    { Faker::Name.last_name }
  let(:email)        { Faker::Internet.email }
  let(:title)        { Faker::Job.title }
  let(:mobile)       { Faker::Number.number(10) }
  let(:employee_num) { Faker::Number.number(10) }
  let(:role)         { Faker::Job.title }
  let(:category)     { Faker::Job.title }
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not to find the title on the page"?

Comment: I mean that as part of my feature test I check to make sure that the title, role and category does not appear on the page. My question is why is `Faker::Job.title` generating strings that are clearly not titles?

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't brilliantly worded. I updated the question to make it a little clearer.

Comment: Which version of Faker are you using? And can you post the snippet of erb that references the category/role/title?

Comment: Using Faker version 1.9.1 and the snippet is actually from the RSpec feature test and it's simply `expect(page).not_to have_content(signatory.category)`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Faker isn’t set up to make realistic job titles. But it’s easy to make your own random job titles. I would just sample your own custom array, like this:

```
let(:title) { %w[Admin Manager Engineer].sample }
```

Comment: Hmm well it does seem to mostly spit out proper job titles, it's just some of the time. Your solution would certainly work but I'll hold out to see if anybody knows the root cause of why Faker is failing to do what it should.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it pulls strings from its [Lorem Ipsum String Set](https://github.com/stympy/faker/blob/a66c1b3fb8ff06ca96509876da4fc2df72bcdc7e/lib/locales/en/lorem.yml) for some reason. Do you mind sharing your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex matcher with word boundaries instead of the short string only, but it is still not bullet-proof.

```
let(:first_name)   { /\b#{Faker::Name.first_name}\b/ }
```

But maybe it is better to stub the attribute on model itself and raise an Error if it is called.